# How can I suggest a change in the login program?

Tags: bugs

Where online is the best place to make new suggestions to ***LINUX*** programmers responsible for maintaining and changing the internals of the *LOGIN* command?

Comment: What is your idea?

Comment: There is no such thing as UN*X. There used to be a product called UNIX but that was a long time ago. Now there are many Unix variants, maintained by different people. So the first thing you need to do is identify which Unix variant you're using. Then you can go and find who maintains their login command (there's no LOGIN command, by the way).

Comment: @michas, my idea is server-side, field-based, user-designed passwords. **The 60/60 Rule* applies: it's hard to describe via keyboard, but super easy on the phone. _(e.g., part of my passwords include the last N characters from the website I'm logging into. Other fields could be served as well. They're surprisingly easy to remember, and it trumps hackers, as the password could be continually changing.)_

Answer (score 1):

Manual page for [`login(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/login) on linux shows at least two mail addresses for authors and other important details. Provided that `login` is part of kernel, you should try some of the [kernel util-linux mailing lists](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#util-linux).

Comment: It is part of kernel?

Comment: Linux implementation is part of kernel. If you want to discuss some other specification, you need to be more precise.